# What happens to the Flutter App if some packages used by it is discontinued or changed?

Tags: flutter

So I wanted to know that, if some packages that I use in my app like drawer, animation, colors gets discontinued or changed will my App stop working those particular features or not?

Answer (score 2):

If a package is published to pub.dev,it cannot be removed, so you will always be able to use it (https://pub.dev/help/publishing#discontinuing-a-package). If a package changes, then the new version of the package might not do what it used to any longer, however, you can (and should) version your dependencies in your project, and you can depend on an older version of a package, if need be.